# python dataframe of Euclidean distance

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
x1  y1  z1  s1  x2  y2  z2  s2  x3  y3  z3  s3  x4  y4  z4  s4  xto yto zto 
1    1  1   1   1   4   5   7   11  17  89  34  1   1   1   1   1   1    1 
4   4   4   1   4   5   7   10  17  79  34  31  51  51  19  10  61  21  20 
4   4   4   1   4   5   7   10  17  79  34  31  51  51  19  10  61  21  20 
4   4   4   1   4   5   7   10  17  79  34  31  51  51  19  10  61  21  20
```

I need please the  euclidean distance  also:

```
d1 = sqr(x1-xto)^2+(y1-yt0)^2+(z1-zto)^2 
d2 = sqr(x2-xto)^2+(y2-yt0)^2+(z2-zto)^2
d3 = sqr(x3-xto)^2+(y3-yt0)^2+(z3-zto)^2 
d4 = sqr(x4-xto)^2+(y4-yt0)^2+(z4-zto)^2
```

to get a new dataframe. something like this:

```
d1  s1 d2 s2 d3 s3 d4 s4 
02  31 41 52 63 54 55 85 
02  71 81 52 63 54 55 85 
02  51 41 52 63 54 55 85  
02  31 41 52 63 54 55 85
```

Comment: how to properly represent the table as you did above?

Comment: usually text with gray background is code. You can highlight the text and press the code button (has {} brackets) or use the proper spacing to get properly format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [SciPy Library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html), there is a method for calculating the Euclidean distance. The argument for the method is array like so you should be able to feed in columns from a pd.df

You can then make list of distances and put them in a dataframe

Comment: You can also use [`numpy.linalg.norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html).  The default order of `None` is the 2-norm a.k.a. Euclidean distance.

Comment: did you try doing math with each column? you can do something like `col1 = np.array(df.iloc[:,0])` and then somethiing like `np.sqrt(col1**2+col5**2)`